# How to pass different calculated values to asp column chart label?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, charts

I have two integer values ta and thc and I'm making the percentage calculation for these two values and pass these values to asp chart labels on each column as shown in the below code.

```
while (myread2.Read())
{
      while (myread.Read())
      {
           string ta1 = myread["totalapplied"].ToString();
           string thc1 = myread2["THC"].ToString();
           Int32 ta = Convert.ToInt32(ta1);
           Int32 thc = Convert.ToInt32(thc1);
           var calc = (((double)ta / (double)thc) * 100);
           string percentCalc = Convert.ToString(String.Format("{0:0.00}", calc)); // I want to pass this value for each column for each read on the loop
           lblcount.Text = myread["totalapplied"].ToString();
           this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(myread["categ"], myread["totalapplied"]);
           this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "Leg";
           Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
           Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = percentCalc; //I need the calculated value here
           Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Shift: #VALX \\nCount: #VALY";
           Chart1.Legends.Clear();
           Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
           Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
       }
       this.Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(myread2["date1"], myread2["THC"]);
       this.Chart1.Series["Series2"].Legend = "Leg";
       Chart1.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
       Chart1.Series["Series2"].Label = "100%";
       Chart1.Series["Series2"].ToolTip = "Shift: #VALX \\nCount: #VALY";
       Chart1.Legends.Clear();
       Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
       Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
       Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
       Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45;
 }
 con.Close();
```

So from the above code, it repeats the very last value of the loop to each and every column of the chart. How can I pass the individual calculations to the label? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to add a custom label to your Series 1's points. Can you tell me if this works?

Instead of this line of code:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = percentCalc;
```

Try this

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Count-1].Label = percentCalc.ToString();
```

Comment: Excellent! You also have access to the .LabelAngle, .LabelToolTip, and .LabelUrl properties off of the Series collection. Experiment with those too!